# Cannot save value in span control using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver + Java to do automation tests and stuck with the problem of setting a value in **span** control.
I have a drop-down with list of clients, the 1st client is selected by default - 'Harry', but I need to change the client to be other than default, e.g. to 'Simon'.

I tried to search here and came with the following code:

```
Webelement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"SelectedClientDirectorID_chosen\"]/a/span"));                                                
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = 'Simon'", element);
```

It seems to be fine, the element is found, it's innerText property is changed to 'Simon' while script is being executed. 
But as soon as I click 'save' button on the page, the record is saved with the 1st value - 'Harry'.

I could not find the answer on why the new value is not saved.

Html looks like:

```html
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 100%;" title="" id="SelectedClientDirectorID_chosen">
 <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
 <span class="">Harry</span>
 <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results">
   <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Harry</li>
   <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Simon</li>
   <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Robin</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Brian</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Rupert</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Greg</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `innerText` value might not bring expected result in your case. You can try to click on drop-down and select required option just like real user do:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathForDropDownButton")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Simon']")).click();
```

You might also need to wait some time until required elements become clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpathForDropDownButton"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='Simon']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for the same. Instead of setting innerText, you need to select value from dropdown.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chosen-results']/li[normalize-space()='Simon']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```